# Iterate though a column in pandas and replace with specific values

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I want to go though a column in a pd dataframe and replace all the corresponding values with the appropriate values.

values range from 1-46 in column A.

```
x=0
y=1000


1=0
2=1
3-22=x+50
23-46=y+100


Input:
Column A

1
2
3
4
23
24


Expected Output:
0
1
50
100
1100
1200
```

Comment: why 24 became 1200 ?

Comment: Each iteration between 23-46 adds 100 starting at 1000. so 23=1100, 24=1200,25=1300, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with a `lambda` function that maps each old value to its new one (using formulas I guessed from your example):

```
...

x=0
y=1000

df['A'] = df['A'].map(lambda n:
  n - 1 if n <= 2 else (
    x + 50 * (n - 2) if 3 <= n <= 22 else (
      y + 100 * (n - 22)
    )
  )
)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      A
0     0
1     1
2    50
3   100
4  1100
5  1200
```